# SEO friendly URLs (.htaccess)

Tags: url, .htaccess, seo

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/file?x=1&y=2
```

Change to:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/file/1/2/
```

---

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/?x=1
```

Change to:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/1/
```

---

I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/$ folder/index.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/file/(.*)/(.*)/$ folder/file.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
```

but that doesn't work, does anyone have any idea why?

when i take out the first rule, i can access the second one via:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/1/2/
```

but not:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/file/1/2/
```

god, i hope i am not confusing anyone who is reading this lol i hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/file/(.*)/(.*)/ /folder/file.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/ /folder/index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

The order of the rules is important. You should always put the one with the most rules first as your way was getting to the first rule and then stopping because it was always true due to the `(.*)` which was capturing the `file`.

Comment: thanks. but it still doesn't work. now only the second rule works. :/

Comment: + notice that you have to create .htaccess file in the root yourself if you don't already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a / before the folder name?

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/$ /folder/index.php?x=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^folder/file/(.*)/(.*)/$ /folder/file.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]
```

Comment: tried it just now, but didn't work. :/ i can make either one work, but not both.

Comment: try using [NC] instead of [L] at the end of each rule