# Proper mod_rewrite for SEO friendly URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a custom php script, each having a page for page.php?id=[number] and page.php. I've read a few .htaccess tutorials but I don't know which one is the most appropriate way of doing it:
Example,

`page.php?id=12` to `page/id-12/`
and
`page.php` to `page/` AND `page`

Here's what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9])$ /category.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^category/$ /category.php
```

Code above returns 404 not found if i access `category` but appears okay if i access `category/` (with a slash)

Comment: view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504169/seo-friendly-urls-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

All your rules include the slash `/` at the end of `category`, thus of course `category` cannot match it.

```
RewriteRule ^category/?$ /category.php
```

The `?` after `/` makes it optional

Comment: thanks! How about category.php?id=2 how would i do that? I tried using above but it says 404 not found, can there be a combined combination of the two?

Comment: The Querystring (the part after the first `?`) is not part of the path and thus not covered by `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @KingCruch This worked `RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ /category.php?id=$1` Could you check the syntax and see if it's correct? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean `category/id-123` (as mentioned in the question) and not `category.php?id=2` (as mentioned in the comment), than its just because you completely ignore the `id-` part: `RewriteRule ^category/id-([0-9])$ /category.php?id=$1`. In the original rule you want a digit after `/`, what obviously cannot match `i` (from `id-`)