# How to have web pages without .html, .php or .asp extension?

Tags: php, html, url

I know why large website like youtube, stackoverflow use these no-extension file system on their website.

I'd like to know how I can do the same on my website?

Comment: Welcome to the world of [URL rewriting](http://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewriting)

Comment: The question is probably a little too succinct but I don't see how it wasn't "a real question".

Answer (score 8):

This isn't about the filesystem but about the URL you see.

An easy solution is to use .htaccess to map the URL without extension to your PHP files.

From [this online tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=htaccess%20remove%20extension&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/&ei=IEzkUOT9GKmg0QWD74G4BA&usg=AFQjCNFUW2MyFZs6W5GRmQOFyDF2-QHWpA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&cad=rja) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by rewriting URLs, for example using Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite Rewrite Rule generator will take a dynamic url given to it, and generate the correct syntax to place in a .htaccess file to allow the url to be rewritten in a spiderable format. The apache module "mod_rewrite" (which you need to enable) converts urls in a certain format to another format, and can be very useful in helping a site with dynamic content to be indexed.

```
Syntax: RewriteRule url-pattern url-new [[flag,...]]
Example: RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*)$ /bar/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

For apache servers you can use .htaccess file with Rewrite functions.
[SEO friendly URLs (.htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504169/seo-friendly-urls-htaccess)
You can find many tutorials for ModRewrite.